# Crash when applying filter to AVVideoComposition

Tags: ios, video, filter

I want to apply filter to AVVideoComposition by function:

`init(asset: AVAsset, applyingCIFiltersWithHandler: (AVAsynchronousCIImageFilteringRequest) -> Void)`

In which, the `asset` is `AVComposition`. When an `AVPlayerItem` plays this composition with the videoComposition, app crashes with error:

`reason: '*** -[AVCoreImageFilterCustomVideoCompositor startVideoCompositionRequest:] Expecting video composition to contain only AVCoreImageFilterVideoCompositionInstruction'`

I wonder how to fix the crash.

PS: I have two videoTracks in composition, each timeRange has its instruction

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are trying to add AVVideoCompositionLayerInstruction to the AVVideoComposition.

Try the simple approach first and see if you need any changes:

```
AVURLAsset *asset = [AVURLAsset assetWithURL:videoURL];
CIFilter *filter = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CIHueAdjust"]; // the filter you want to add: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CoreImageFilterReference/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/filter/ci/
AVMutableVideoComposition *videoComposition = [AVMutableVideoComposition videoCompositionWithAsset:asset applyingCIFiltersWithHandler:^(AVAsynchronousCIImageFilteringRequest * _Nonnull request) {
    // set filter input image
[filter setDefaults];
    [filter setValue:sourceImage forKey:kCIInputImageKey];

    // hue
    NSNumber *angle = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.8];
    [filter setValue:angle forKey:kCIInputAngleKey];

    CIImage *outputImage = filter.outputImage;
    [request finishWithImage:outputImage context:nil];
}];

AVAssetExportSession *exportSession = [[AVAssetExportSession alloc] initWithAsset:asset presetName:AVAssetExportPreset1920x1080];
exportSession.outputFileType = AVFileTypeQuickTimeMovie;
exportSession.outputURL = outputURL;
exportSession.videoComposition = videoComposition;

// export the session async
[exportSession exportAsynchronouslyWithCompletionHandler:^{
    switch (exportSession.status) {
        case AVAssetExportSessionStatusCompleted:
            NSLog(@"Yeah!");
            break;

        default:
            NSLog(@"Nooo!");
            break;
    }
}];
```

Comment: Any chance you managed to solve the rotation issue with a custom AVVideoCompositing class? It's not respecting the asset transform, all the CIFilters in the request are always in landscape... We stuck on this for over a week ah

Answer (score 1):

You can't use both `AVVideoCompositionLayerInstruction` and `applyingCIFiltersWithHandler`.

Intead, you need to apply directly the transform in the filter.

This can be done by applying it to the source image.

`request.sourceImage.transformed(by: transform)`

Answer (score 0):

AVMutableVideoComposition:videoCompositionWithAsset:applyingCIFiltersWithHandler only support iOS 9+ and if you only need export video with CIFilter, that's ok.

Configure more videoComposition instructions will cash, for example add kind of roateLayerInstruction to AVAssetTrack.

I have same issue in this situation and custom AVVideoCompositing maybe the better solution. some good demos about how to customize videoCompositor [demo1](https://github.com/claygarrett/CustomVideoCompositor) [demo2](https://github.com/grassel/AVCustomEdit.git).

I am working on this problem this week.

Comment: Any chance you managed to solve the rotation issue with AVVideoCompositing, it's not respecting the asset transform, all the CIFilters in the request are always in landscape...

Comment: @RoiMulia see my answer, I think it should solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was implementing a custom compositor class as outlined here: [Rendering a video in a CALayer hierarchy using CIFilters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58539078/rendering-a-video-in-a-calayer-hierarchy-using-cifilters)

If you need to apply transforms, I modified that answer's code from:

```
filter.setValue(CIImage(cvPixelBuffer: frame), forKey: kCIInputImageKey)
if let outputImage = filter.outputImage... etc
```

to:

```
filter.setValue(CIImage(cvPixelBuffer: frame), forKey: kCIInputImageKey)
let outputImage = filter.outputImage?.transformed(by: transformforCompositor)
if let outputImage = outputImage... etc
```