# Rendering a video in a CALayer hierarchy using CIFilters

Tags: ios, avfoundation, cifilter, avasset, core-video

In the UI of my iOS app, I display a complex hierarchy of `CALayer`s. One of these layers is a `AVPlayerLayer` that displays a video with `CIFilter`s applied in real time (using `AVVideoComposition(asset:, applyingCIFiltersWithHandler:)`).

Now I want to export this layer composition to a video file. There are two tools in `AVFoundation` that seem helpful:

**A**: `AVVideoCompositionCoreAnimationTool` which allows rendering a video inside a (possibly animated) `CALayer` hierarchy

**B**: `AVVideoComposition(asset:, applyingCIFiltersWithHandler:)`, which I also use in the UI, to apply `CIFilter`s to a video asset.

However, these two tools cannot be used simultaneously: If I start an `AVAssetExportSession` that combines these tools, `AVFoundation` throws an `NSInvalidArgumentException`:

> Expecting video composition to contain only `AVCoreImageFilterVideoCompositionInstruction`

I tried to workaround this limitation as follows:

**Workaround 1**

1) Setup an export using `AVAssetReader` and `AVAssetWriter`

2) Obtain the sample buffers from the asset reader and apply the `CIFilter`, save the result in a `CGImage`.

3) Set the `CGImage` as the `content` of the video layer in the layer hierarchy. Now the layer hierarchy "looks like" one frame of the final video.

4) Obtain the data of the `CVPixelBuffer` for each frame from the asset writer using `CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddress` and create a `CGContext` with that data.

5) Render my layer to that context using `CALayer.render(in ctx: CGContext)`.

This setup works, but is extremely slow - exporting a 5 second video sometimes takes a minute. It looks like the `CoreGraphics` calls are the bottleneck here (I guess that's because with this approach the composition happens on the CPU?)

**Workaround 2**

One other approach could be to do this in two steps: First, save the source video just with the filters applied to a file as in **B**, and then use that video file to embed the video in the layer composition as in **A**. However, as it uses two passes, I guess this isn't as efficient as it could be.

**Summary**

What is a good approach to export this video to a file, ideally in a single pass? How can I use `CIFilter`s and `AVVideoCompositionCoreAnimationTool` simultaneously? Is there a native way to set up a "pipeline" in `AVFoundation` which combines these tools?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The way to achieve this is using a custom `AVVideoCompositing`. This object allows you to compose (in this case apply the CIFilter) each video frame.

Here's an example implementation that applies a `CIPhotoEffectNoir` effect to the whole video:

```
class VideoFilterCompositor: NSObject, AVVideoCompositing {

    var sourcePixelBufferAttributes: [String : Any]? = [kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey as String: kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA]
    var requiredPixelBufferAttributesForRenderContext: [String : Any] = [kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey as String: kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA]
    private var renderContext: AVVideoCompositionRenderContext?

    func renderContextChanged(_ newRenderContext: AVVideoCompositionRenderContext) {
        renderContext = newRenderContext
    }

    func cancelAllPendingVideoCompositionRequests() {
    }

    private let filter = CIFilter(name: "CIPhotoEffectNoir")!
    private let context = CIContext()
    func startRequest(_ asyncVideoCompositionRequest: AVAsynchronousVideoCompositionRequest) {
        guard let track = asyncVideoCompositionRequest.sourceTrackIDs.first?.int32Value, let frame = asyncVideoCompositionRequest.sourceFrame(byTrackID: track) else {
            asyncVideoCompositionRequest.finish(with: NSError(domain: "VideoFilterCompositor", code: 0, userInfo: nil))
            return
        }
        filter.setValue(CIImage(cvPixelBuffer: frame), forKey: kCIInputImageKey)
        if let outputImage = filter.outputImage, let outBuffer = renderContext?.newPixelBuffer() {
            context.render(outputImage, to: outBuffer)
            asyncVideoCompositionRequest.finish(withComposedVideoFrame: outBuffer)
        } else {
            asyncVideoCompositionRequest.finish(with: NSError(domain: "VideoFilterCompositor", code: 0, userInfo: nil))
        }
    }

}
```

If you need to have different filters at different times, you can use custom `AVVideoCompositionInstructionProtocol` which you can get from the `AVAsynchronousVideoCompositionRequest`

Next, you need to use this with your `AVMutableVideoComposition`, so:

```
let videoComposition = AVMutableVideoComposition()
videoComposition.customVideoCompositorClass = VideoFilterCompositor.self
//Add your animator tool as usual
let animator = AVVideoCompositionCoreAnimationTool(postProcessingAsVideoLayer: v, in: p)
videoComposition.animationTool = animator
//Finish setting up the composition
```

With this, you should be able to export the video using a regular `AVAssetExportSession`, setting its `videoComposition`

Comment: Great solution! Thanks!

Comment: Does anyone have a sample project to see the full code of how to apply this? I.e. can the AVMutableVideoComposition be applied in AVCaptureMovieFileOutput or must it be applied in captureOutput(_ output: AVCaptureOutput, didOutput sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer, from connection: AVCaptureConnection)?

Comment: @PederWessel, Here's a similar example. https://github.com/claygarrett/CustomVideoCompositor
I follows similar approach to pass CIFilter as instruction.

Comment: If you need to also apply transforms, you can do so after the filter.setValue line by adding let outputImage = filter.outputImage?.transformed(by: transformforCompositor). Then, if let outputImage = filter.outputImage becomes if let outputImage = outputImage.